# How to get int type data from firebase real time database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to get the value of an int type from my database but it returns a null value i used a future to prevent that but still same problem it returns null

I tried calling the method inside the build function and also outside the build even went a step further to call it inside initState but no success whats the problem?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){...}
int getSnapShotDataAsInt(String child){
  FutureBuilder(
    future: databaseReference
      .child("users")
      .child(_firebaseUser.uid)
      .child(child)
      .once(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
        return snapshot.data.value;
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Statements like "but no success" and "it didnt work for me" are incredibly difficult to help with. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, and we need to know exactly what line didn't do what you expected it to do, and what it did instead. So if you set a breakpoint on `return snapshot.data.value`, what value does `snapshot.data.value` show? Can you `print` that value, and show us the updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: It'd also be good to see the JSON at `/users/$uid` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your ".value", the correct call as per documentation is:

```
return snapshot.data.val();
```

I believe you can optionally pass a data type into those brackets to attempt conversion to specific data type.
Such as:

```
return snapshot.data.val(String); (etc)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val